# Table design for departments with duplicate department numbers

Tags: oracle, database-design, primary-key

How should I define a database table for my company's departments where we have a set of duplicate department numbers used by an upper management tier.

```
  dept_id   dept_name   manager_id  director_id   vp_id   description     mission_statement  over_view    web_url
      1       name1      10            20          30       ...
      2       name2      11            21          30
      3       name3      12            22          31
      4       name4      13            23          32
      4       name5      13            24          32
      4       name6      13            25          32
```

The column which makes the row unique is the director_id.  But I really only want to use the dept_id as the pk because I'm using the department data for a web application. I have the `Employee` table with a column named `dept_id`.  When I display an employee on a webpage, I dynamically create a link to the department's splash page containing the above information.  But if I list `director 24` I need URL parameters that take me to the department named `name5`

`blahblah.com/view_dept.jsp?dept_id=4`

I know the obvious is to composite key with `director_id`  and have the URL be

`blahblah.com/view_dept.jsp?dept_id=4&director_id=24`

but when I list a regular employee I don't have the director_id. I suppose I could get it in the query, but it may not be as straight forward as it would be if HR just used unique ID's for all departments. Getting HR to do a reorg is probably out of the question, but it would be nice to know that that is the most recommended answer.

I'd like to hear suggestions and best alternatives to the reorg

Comment: I'm not sure that I follow.  If the `employee` table has just a `dept_id` and no `director_id`, how would you ever figure out whether an employee with a `dept_id` of 4 was in the department name4, name5, or name6?

Comment: right. this is the dilema. its only the directors which are in a dept with a duplicate dept number but unique name.  If I only use dept_id as the dept table's PK, I can't even load the duplicate depts   The employee table has a supervisor_id so I could through a connect_by determine the chain of command.

Comment: Are you replicating the `employee` and `department` tables from the same system (or two different systems) into a new system that you're building?  Or are you re-designing an existing system?  How, exactly, would you figure out which department an employee is in using the existing data model?  Is that how the existing system really figures out which department an employee is in?

Comment: Employee table is db View I get from our IT group.   Departments are in an Excel document, thus the non-normalize dataset.

Comment: So there is a system with an existing `employee` table that has a `dept_id` column but there is no existing `department` table where this value can be looked up?  So, currently, you can't determine the name of the department an employee is in?

Comment: Right, I am trying to model our organizations departments in an Oracle table based off of a spreadsheet that HR maintains.  Certainly I could allow a duplicate department number in my Oracle table but then in my web app, I would return a list of department names when I programmatically build a html links to the department from an employee listings if their dept number was 4. As in blahblah.com/view_dept.jsp?dept_id=4        blahblah.com/view_dept.jsp?dept_id=2 however returns a single row

Comment: use the Party Model and the Party Role Model

Answer (score 1):

The PK of your department table *is not* `dept_id`.  The column `dept_id` is an attribute of a `manager` table that you have not defined, since it is functionally dependent on the `manager_id`.

The PK of your department table is `dept_name`.

Primary keys don't have to be integers.

*Note:* If your HR department creates departments with the same name, that is going to land you back in hot water.  You might need to create a composite primary key of `dept_id` and `dept_name`.  This could still lead to trouble if your HR department can't be trained to keep department names unique within managers.  Excel is not a good data source for being able to enforce constraints.

Comment: interesting. If I didn't have duplicate dept numbers would you still suggest a separate Managers Table? Would you also suggest breaking out a Director Table and VP Table?  Even if I had separate tables how I can determine a department NAME that a regular employee is in?  In the employee table their dept number is listed.  I want to join to some table(s) get the department name. I'd have to determine the employees Manager, then join manager_id to department table.  If dept number happens to be 4 (the duplicate), I'm screwed. If HR didn't have duplicate dept numbers, the query would be trivial.

Comment: @jeff - The issue is about normalization based on functional dependencies.  For a logical model you probably would have separate director and VP tables.  That doesn't mean your physical model needs them.  It may be, based on what you say about employee-department mapping that the PK of department is a _composite_ of `dept_id` and `manager_id`.  That would also work and it might solve your problem of how to join `employee` in.  I assume your employee table has a `manager_id` and a `dept_id` so that would solve your problem.